# Store 2000 images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core, azure-storage

I am implementing a web application which uses React as front end and Asp.net as backend. I have around 2000 images that has to be used in the web application. What will be best way to store these images ?

Comment: https://cloudinary.com/ seems like a great option and I'm going to use it for a project shortly. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudinary

Comment: What's wrong with storing them in the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is **never store any media yourself**.

Since serving any image/video content **relies heavily on your network/bandwidth**, it is not always stable and vulnerable to the slightest DDoS attack. Let alone that the security of your server may not be enough to protect your data.

I would highly recommend you to lookup some CDN, or Content Delivery Network, provider, such as AWS and GCD. You may also set up access right and serve criteria to better protect your data in these providers.

Reference:[Why Use CDN’s for Your Website & Image Hosting](https://www.globo.tech/learning-center/why-use-cdns-for-your-image-hosting/)

Edit: I just noticed that you have tagged your question with `azure-storage`, which is also a great option for serving media over the internet.

Comment: Thanks. Yes i have plans to use azure storage

Comment: Glad it helped!